# Matching system date to select file SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a list of files in a directory `/XX/XX_XX/XX` that have the date as YYYYMMDD after the file name

```
Files20130726.xxx
Files20130727.xxx
Files20130728.xxx
Files20130729.xxx
Files20130730.xxx
Files20130731.xxx
```

I need to take the current system date and select the file that has the matching date

Example: (system date 7/31/2013 = File20130731.xxx)

I created a procedure that will select the file with the correct system date from the directory

```
PROCEDURE xxxxxx
   uu_f_name VARCHAR2(20) := 'Files.xxx';          
   uu_infile   utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
  CREATE DIRECTORY NEW_DIRECTORY as '/XX/XX_XX/XX';
  uu_infile := utl_file.fopen('/XX/XX_XX/XX', to_date(substr(uu_f_name,6, sysdate), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'r');
```

1. I don't really know how to declare the Files.xxx because it actually FilesYYYYMMDD.xxx (so not sure if I can just declare it as 'FilesYYYYMMDD')
2. I am stuck on how to select the current system date and match it with the correct file. This is what I have but I know that it is not correct but I am lost at how to do this.

   `to_date(substr(uu_f_name,6, sysdate), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'r');`

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle?

Comment: Yes I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself familiar with:

- [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm).
- How to convert strings to dates and other way round with [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm) and [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm) functions that use format models.
- How to concatenate strings with [`concat` function and `||` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions033.htm).

There's plenty of questions here about all of these subjects you can learn from.

Example that should get you started:

```
JANI@xe> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2013-08-01 07:52:55

JANI@xe> select 'Files.' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') || '.xxx' as filename from dual;

FILENAME
------------------
Files.20130801.xxx

JANI@xe> !cat so25.sql
declare
  v_filename constant varchar2(32767) :=
    'Files.' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') || '.xxx';
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('v_filename = ' || v_filename);
end;
/
JANI@xe> @so25.sql
v_filename = Files.20130801.xxx

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

JANI@xe>
```

After that we can come back to your `UTL_FILE` issues if you have any.